# How to do search of part of a word using lucene?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

Its Ershad here.I am working on lucene.
Now i am able to search the word.But if i type part of word, i am unable to get the results.
Can you pls suggest what to be done.

For indexing, i am using the below code

```
writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
writer.SetUseCompoundFile(true);

doc.Add(Field.UnStored("text", parseHtml(html)));
doc.Add(Field.Keyword("path", relativePath));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

For searching, i am using the below code.

```
Query query = QueryParser.Parse(this.Query,"text",new StandardAnalyzer());

// create the result DataTable
this.Results.Columns.Add("title", typeof(string));
this.Results.Columns.Add("sample", typeof(string));
this.Results.Columns.Add("path", typeof(string));

// search
Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);

this.total = hits.Length();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you refer to [the Lucene Query Parser Syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches), you will find that you can append an asterisk (`*`) to the end of your query to match all those words that begin with a particular string. For example, suppose you want to get results mentioning both "caterpillar" and "catamaran". Your search query would be "cat*".

However, if you are not in direct control of the search query (for example, if the user is entering their own search queries), then you may need a little trickery on the part of the `QueryParser`. My experience is solely with the Java version of Lucene. Hopefully the principles are the same with Lucene.NET.

In Java, you could extend the `QueryParser` class and override its `newTermQuery(Term)` method. Traditionally, this method would return a `TermQuery` object. However, the child class would instead return a `PrefixQuery`. For example:

```
public class PrefixedTermsQueryParser extends QueryParser {

    // Some constructors...

    protected Query newTermQuery(Term term) {
        return new PrefixQuery(term);
    }

}
```

I am not terribly sure what methods you could override in Lucene.NET, but I am sure there must be something similar. Looking at [its documentation](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/), it appears [the QueryParser class](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParserMembers.html) has a method called `GetFieldQuery`. Perhaps this is the method you would have to override.

Comment: Hi Adam,

Thanks for the reply.
Thanks for the documentation links.I will try this and reply to you.

Comment: The documentation links are broken